# Get related post from multiple Taxonomies

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have two custom post types named as `publication` and `service`.

I post articles and brochures under publication with two different categories those are `publication-service` and `publication-type`.

publication-service indicates that what service this publication falls into.

On the other hand, the publication-type indicates what kind of publication is this resource.

The service post type also has the same category types as publication, it is duplicated category types.

So I've created a relationship between publication and services with below code to list down publication posts in service pages. The code works perfectly and I can create a relationship between any service and publication. For example, one of the services listed on the website is **Education** and at the same time, I have some brochures and articles posts related education service. By applying the below code, I can list down the posts those related the respective services.

What exactly I want to do is adding one more taxonomy as publication-type into below code and by doing so I can choose the type of publication that I want to list down in service pages because currently all the publication types (brochures, articles) posts displayed in service page. I want to narrow down it.

I hope you understand what I am trying to explain, this is the website structure with services and publications.

[image]

Can you guys pls help on this?

```
<?php

  $custom_terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'publication-service');

  if( $custom_terms ){


      $tax_query = array();


      if( count( $custom_terms > 1 ) )
          $tax_query['relation'] = 'OR' ;


      foreach( $custom_terms as $custom_term ) {

          $tax_query[] = array(
              'taxonomy' => 'publication-service',
              'field' => 'slug',
              'terms' => $custom_term->slug,
          );

      }


      $args = array( 'post_type' => 'publication',
                      'posts_per_page' => 5,
                      'tax_query' => $tax_query );


      $loop = new WP_Query($args);

      if( $loop->have_posts() ) {

          while( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="item">
        <div class="listing-title">
          <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="underline"><?php the_title() ?></a>
        </div>
        <div class="listing-image">
          <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" style="background-image: url('<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(), 'full') ?>')"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
          <?php

          endwhile;

      }

      wp_reset_query();

  }?>
```

Comment: Take a look at the documentation - [Multiple Taxonomy Parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters).

Comment: @IvankaTodorova yeah I've tried it but some how I couldnt manage combine that query with mine. I failed several times. I am not really good at php.